# Checking this network connection (port forwarding)

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

I have the below setup, I want to be be able to reach the device (192.168.2.180 eth) from my desktop (192.168.1.3 wifi) I have a linux server in the middle (192.168.1.111 WIFI), (192.168.2.22 Eth)

From my desktop I can ping the ehternet adaptor on the linux server (192.168.2.22) but not the device (192.168.2.180). I can ping this device from the linux server so it is reachable.

I can even ping from the device(192.168.2.180) back to my desktop (192.168.1.3)

I have setup routes on the desktop;

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway           Interface    Metric
192.168.2.0              255.255.255.0    192.168.1.111      192.168.1.3     26
```

I have enabled port forwarding on the linux machine and setup routes;

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.111 metric 600
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.22 metric 100
```

I have enabled a rule on the device

```
   Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway           Interface    Metric
    192.168.1.0              255.255.255.0    192.168.2.22      192.168.2.180     26
```

I have enabled the firewall rule to allow ping requests on the windows devices and disabled the ufw (for now) on the linux machine.

when I carry out a tracecert from 192.168.1.3 to 192.168.2.180 it gets to the linux server times out.

```
PS C:\Users\someUser> tracert 192.168.2.180

Tracing route to 192.168.2.180 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1   538 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.111
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

my linux server must know what to do with a 192.168.2.x packet as I can ping the eth adapter 192.168.2.22 but it cannot get further.

what else should I be looking at?

[image: Network image, notice ping only one way between 192.168.2.180 and 192.168.1.3]